# "Даже если мы не выйдем в финал, мы будем рады, что прошли так далеко"

Tags: синтаксис, наклонение

Использование наклонения в придаточных уступки всегда слабая тема для меня, прошу вашей помощи еще раз. 
Поняла из ранних ваших ответов, что есть реальные и ирреальные уступки.
Пример:

> **Даже если мы не выйдем в финал**, мы будем рады, что прошли так далеко.

Понимаю, наши языки разные, поэтому хочу объяснить, что мне тяжело понять: мы будем использовать сослагательное наклонение в этом придаточном, потому что описанное действие отнесено к будущему, оно гипотетическое и пока не является фактом (поэтому голова не принимает индикатив в таком контексте).

Если вы тоже выделяете реальные и ирреальные уступки, почему интерпретируете "даже если мы не выйдем в финал" индикативно (действие еще не случилось ведь)?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Ошибка: вместо "_пришли_" должно быть "_прошли_".

Comment: Freim: feel free to correct it, dear! i'm not a native speaker

Comment: Just replace that word; the rest of the sentence is ok.

Answer (score 1):

***Даже если*** мы **не выйде**м в финал, мы **будем рады**, что прошли так далеко.

1) В этом предложении используется **условный** союз ЕСЛИ, но частица ДАЖЕ (союзный комплекс ДАЖЕ ЕСЛИ) придает ему **уступительный** характер (уступка связана с **противоречивостью** ситуации: **хотя и** не выйдем, **но** все равно будем рады).

2) Это **потенциальная (гипотетическая) уступка,** так как она отнесена к будущему времени, а значение будущего времени может выражать **изъявительное** наклонение (индикатив).

3) **Сослагательное наклонение** обычно используется для обозначения **ирреальной (контрфактической) ситуации**, которая могла бы осуществиться, но не осуществилась. В данном случае это выглядело бы так:

***Даже если бы мы не вышли*** в финал, то все равно **были бы рады**, что прошли так далеко. (А мы вышли в финал!)

4) Такие же примеры можно привести для чисто условных придаточных (без значения уступки).

Если команда **не выйдет** в финал, то это **будет** неудивительно. Это потенциальное условие, будущее время, изъявительное наклонение.

*Если команда **вышла бы** в финал, то это **было бы** удивительно.* **Ирреальное** (контрфактическое) условие, так как команда действительно не вышла в финал.